# Here API batch distance calculation

Tags: here-api

Currently, is there a way to submit a list of origin and destination to Here API to batch processing and get driving distance? I saw supports said there was no such way but that was 6 months ago. I wonder if they developed the product now?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Matrix Routing API with asynchronous option.

**Here Matrix Routing API**

The Matrix Routing service fulfills a single purpose: it calculates routing matrices (of travel times and/or distances). It supports matrices of any size up to 10,000 x 10,000.

This service is for you if you need to calculate a routing matrix

1. with custom options and dynamic traffic applied, given the origins and destinations are within a certain region with diameter up to 400 km, or
2. with routes of arbitrary length given a predefined set of options that can be used with free-flow speed traffic applied, or
3. with custom options, dynamic traffic and no region size limitation, for up to 15 origins and 100 destinations, or up to 100 origins and 1 destination.

*Sample code:*

JSON Request Body:

```json
{
    "origins": [{"lat": 0.0, "lng": 0.0}, {"lat": 0.1, "lng": 0.1}, ...],
    "destinations": [...],  // if omitted, origins are used as destinations
    "regionDefinition": {
        "type": "circle",
        "center": {"lat": 0.0, "lng": 0.0},
        "radius": 10000
    }
}
```

For more options you can look at [Here Documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/matrix-routing-api/8.3.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started/asynchronous-request.html)